# Is there a way in matlab to load a .mat file containing a table as a tall array?

Tags: matlab

I have tables saved on .mat files which are quite heavy and take some time to load. I also dont think they can be saved in a way that I can access them as datastores as they contain cell arrays. To cut off computation time I would like to use them as tall arrays which might save up some iterations through the columns.
'*myTallArray = tall(myTable)*' does the trick yet I would like to know if there is a way to cut the '*myTable = load(myTable.mat)*' middle man and load it as a tall array.

Comment: You can load single variables from the MAT-file. One option would be to load each of them in turn, and save them as tall arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why won't you save myTallArray once

```
myTallArray = tall(myTable)
save('myTallTable.mat','myTallArray')
```

and then load it as usual

```
load('myTallTable.mat')
```